# Warning message of timezone in R POSIXlt(as.POSIXlt(x)

Tags: r, timezone, posixlt

I've downgrade R in MacOS from 3.4 to 3.2
Now I'm having these warning messages

```
Warning messages:
1: In format.POSIXlt(as.POSIXlt(x), ...) :
  unknown timezone 'America/Belem'
2: In format.POSIXlt(as.POSIXlt(x), ...) : unknown timezone 'GMT'
3: In format.POSIXlt(as.POSIXlt(x), ...) :
  unknown timezone 'America/New_York'
```

I don't know how to repair it.
My time zone is America/Belem as I've seen it on the `OlsonNames()`

My sytem info:

```
> Sys.info() 
sysname "Darwin" 
release "16.6.0" 
version "Darwin Kernel Version 16.6.0: Fri Apr 14 16:21:16 PDT 2017; 
root:xnu-3789.60.24~6/RELEASE_X86_64" 
nodename "RobertaMBPro.local" 
machine "x86_64"
```

May I ask some help with it?
Thank you

Comment: Can you please copy the information of `Sys.info()` so we know what system you're working on. MacOS is notorious for compatibility issues (not only with R btw), so the exact version is rather important.

Comment: Why did you downgrade? How did you downgrade? What code throws the warnings?

Comment: Hi @JorisMeys, here it is > Sys.info()
 sysname  "Darwin" 
  release "16.6.0" 
version 
"Darwin Kernel Version 16.6.0: Fri Apr 14 16:21:16 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.60.24~6/RELEASE_X86_64" 
nodename 
"RobertaMBPro.local" 
 machine 
 "x86_64"

Comment: @Roland Because with this new version i was having trouble with a package that is not updated since 2015 and I've downloaded it and installing it directly from a tar.gz. With 3.4 it was not working anymore. I downgrade using brew as it was installed like that and downloaded from R-project the older version. Every code throws these warnings... I have just to use r.

Comment: @Tetraodienne I don't see a particular reason as to why you would get these warnings. Can you give the result of `SessionInfo()` as well? Does this happen from the moment you open R, or only if you load certain packages? If the latter, use `SessionInfo()` after loading these packages so we can try to find where the conflict arises from.

Comment: Another piece of information required: `Sys.getenv("TZDIR")` and `dir(file.path(R.home("share"), "zoneinfo"))`

Comment: Could you also tell _which_ package you installed from source and how you did that? Because downgrading R to be able to work with a package you built from source, doesn't make sense to me.